# URL with diacritics in Latin hexa (php)

Tags: php, url, curl, hex, utf

I don't find the way to convert diacritic and special char to hexa windows-1252. For example 'Décision' to 'D%E9cision' (%E9 not %C3%A9 given by urlencode routine).

I need to cURL a server which doesn't accept another way to request an URL containing diacritics or spaces. See http://www.findinfo-tc.vd.ch/justice/findinfo-pub/html/CREC%20%28d%E8s%202011%29/HC/20160715171616483_e.html

Can anybody show me the light ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`urlencode()` will do, but it's your string that is UTF-8 encoded (comes from utf encoded source - file encoding, database...). You need to change the string charset first:

```
$encoded = urlencode(iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1252', 'Décision'));
```

You might also save such strings in separate file that is Windows-1252 encoded (source code should better stick with utf-8) - You won't need conversion, but it's easy to overlook later and invoke a bug.

Comment: I search many hours. I would have never find ! You save me a lot of frustration, thank you very much.